# Trouble installing emulator software (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, acer-aspire, display-driver, emulator

I have a pretty old but decent laptop, an Acer Aspire 5738Z-4111.

I wanted to install some emulator software but all show that my graphic drivers are out of date (except bluestacks emulator which I have already installed).

Is there a way out to bypass that message or is there any other emulator that I could root and use for my purpose?

Comment: Are your display drivers out of date?  It sounds like that perhaps your hardware does not meet the minimum requirements for these emulators.

Comment: @Ramhound yes everything is on its max upgrade, cant do anything else, still could I get something for me?

Comment: You failed to provide us information on the GPU inside your device.  The `Intel Pentium T4300 ` doesn't have an iGPU.

Comment: I removed the PC specs from the question as I felt they were distracting, especially as the author hadn't included the make/model of their graphics card.